# Reporting progress on a million call process

Tags: c#-4.0, logging, console-application, progress

I have a console/desktop application that crawls a lot (think million calls) of data from various webservices. At any given time I have about 10 threads performing these call and aggregating the data into a MySql database. All seeds are also stored in a database.

What would be the best way to report it's progress? By progress I mean:

- How many calls already executed
- How many failed
- What's the average call duration
- How much is left

I thought about logging all of them somehow and tailing the log to get the data. Another idea was to offer some kind of output to a always open TCP endpoint where some form of UI could read the data and display some aggregation. Both ways look too rough and too complicated.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you're already using a database, why not have a table that tracks each worker's state?

Comment: is this a website, web application, or a desktop application?

Comment: @Malachi I edited the question to clarify it. Its a console app.

Comment: my Edit over wrote your edit, but I edited it back in, hopefully it works out right.   oops

Answer (score 1):

The "best way" depends on your requirements.  If you use a logging framework like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), you can plug in a variety of logging targets like files, databases, the console or TCP endpoints.

You can also use a viewer like [Harvester](http://harvester.codeplex.com/) as a logging target.

When logging multi-threaded applications I sometimes have an additional thread that writes a summary of progress to the logger once every so often (e.g. every 15 seconds).

Comment: Currently, exception and informational logging is done via log4net.

Comment: NLog allows separate log targets based on a user-assigned name, the class the logger is used from, etc.  Presumably log4net has something similar?  You could define a logger target specifically for progress reporting, so it is not mixed in with the info and exception log(s).

Comment: How about data aggregation? With something like Harvester looks like I would just be sending logs to a remote endpoint instead of a file/database.

Comment: That all depends on what your requirements are.  As stated in my edit, I write an aggregated summary every so often to a log target.  You can also write that data to a file or database, to a named pipe, or to any number of other mechanisms.  All depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

since it is a Console Application, just use `Writeline`, just have the application spit the important stuff out to the Console.

I did something Similar in an application that I created to [export PDF's from a SQL Server Database back into PDF Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813523/exporting-pdfs-from-sql-server-db-and-writing-a-map-to-a-text-file)

you can do it many different ways. if you are counting records and their size you can run a tally of sorts and have it show the total every so many records..

---

I also wrote out to a **Text File**, so that I could keep track of all the PDFs and what case numbers they went to and things like that.  that information is in the answer that I gave to the above linked question.

you could also write things out to a Text File every so often with the statistics.

the logger that **Eric J.** mentions is probably going to be a little bit easier to implement, and would be a nice tool for your toolbox.

these options are just as valid depending on your specific needs.

Comment: One drawback with that is if you need to look back further in the "log" than you have lines of buffer in the console.  Using a logging framework, you can point output to both the console and something like a log file or database at the same time.  Only slightly more setup than Console.WriteLine, especially if you use NuGet to add your reference to the logging framework.

Comment: I agree. let me add a little bit to my answer.